# How are the project titles aligned on this page

Tags: css

Have a look at this page -

http://bilalh.github.com/projects/

The titles of the projects are aligned(vertically) together in both the columns. The positioning is done on based on div and the height of div is variable.

I am trying to do something similar in my site, but the titles do not align vertically.

Can anyone tell me which CSS style is doing the magic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much a style as a complete css framework helping out - it is using the Blueprint CSS framework. Among other things, it makes some very nice, simple grids. Have a look at http://blueprintcss.org/